# External Screen USB-C with Ubuntu 20.04 it works and it doesn't work

Tags: usb, 20.04, monitor, external-monitor, usb-c

I have a Envy 13 2018 with a Blitzwolf screen Bw-pcm2. I conect them through the usb-c interface (send power and display) and the screen dont show any image (it´s not on).

But, if i boot the notebook in diagnostic bios program mode (F2), the notebook send energy to the screen, i exit the mode and the screen it keeps switched on, and i work normally with the second screen without problem.

I must repeat this every time i turn on the notebook, and it's unpleasant. What is the problem?